# How to set log4j2.json configuration.properties.property default value

Tags: log4j2

I have the following log4j2.json:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "name": "MYapp",
    "properties": {
      "property": [
        {"name":"LogFileLocation","value":"/path/to/log"},
        {"name":"AppenderRef", "value":"${env:APPENDER_REF}"}
      ]
    },
  ...
```

Can I somehow specify a default value?  For example, if there is no `APPENDER_REF` environment variable defined, I'd like the default to be `STDOUT` but I can't get something like this to work:

`{"name":"AppenderRef", "value":"${env:APPENDER_REF}", "defaultValue": "STDOUT"}`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found they way to do this:

`{"name":"AppenderRef", "value":"${env:APPENDER_REF:-DefaultValue}"}`

It's similar to bash scripting defaults, I guess...